# How can I receive several inputs from wifi and save them?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I'm trying to send and receive some data from one Arduino to another Arduino. I'm using an Arduino Uno and FS1000A / XY-MK-5V 433Mhz TX/RX Modules. For transmitting I use the Radiohead library.

I want to send two strings and save them as different strings. My receiver code is:

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> // Not actualy used but needed to compile

RH_ASK driver;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
  if (!driver.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t buf[200];
  memset(buf, '\0', 200);
  uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
  if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) {
    // Non-blocking
    Serial.print("Message: ");
    Serial.println((char*)buf);
  }
}
```

First of all, why do I have to use `#include <SPI.h>`? To receive I use:

```
if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) {
  // Non-blocking
  Serial.print("Message: ");
  Serial.println((char*)buf);
}
```

This code saves the output as one output! How can I specify which input is the first one and which is the second one?

Comment: If commenting out `#include <SPI.h>` causes an error, then presumably it is required by `RH_ASK.h`or something it drags in. The buffer `buf`for the received messages is recreated on each loop iteration so previous messages are lost. What do you want to do with 2 consecutive messages, concatenate them together or what?

Comment: I think we'd also need to know what data you are expecting to receive - unless it's always exactly 200 bytes, you'll need a way to tell where it finishes.

Comment: I want to sent two integer ( or I can send them as characters) but I want to save them as two variables.